# Why angular not binding Data in ng-model

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, linq

Here I'm getting data from the database and I also trace that data from Fiddler but when I'm trying to bind data in an angular table it's not binding

**Linq Query**

```
public JsonResult GetSalesData()
        {
            using (Ctxdb dc = new Ctxdb())
            {


                var v = (from a in dc.SalesRecords
                         group a by a.SalesDate.Year into g
                         select new
                         {
                             Year = g.Key,
                             Electronics = g.Sum(a => a.Electronics),
                             BookAndMedia = g.Sum(a => a.BookAndMedia),
                             HomeAndKitchen = g.Sum(a => a.HomeAndKitchen)
                         });
                if (v != null)
                {
                    var chartData = new object[v.Count() + 1];
                    chartData[0] = new object[]{
                "Year",
                "Electronics",
                "Book and Media",
                "Home and KitchenKFC"
            };
                    int j = 0;
                    foreach (var i in v)
                    {
                        j++;
                        chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Year.ToString(), i.Electronics, i.BookAndMedia, i.HomeAndKitchen };}
 return new JsonResult { Data = chartData, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };}}
return new JsonResult { Data = null, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };}
```

**Fidller Data**

```
[["Year","Electronics","Book and Media","Home and KitchenKFC"],["1947",99489,46000,26833],["1995",25555,45000,99000],["2011",1584,5685,5566],["2012",12121,1500,1200],["2014",600,5132,2730],["2015",1789,1255,1258]]
```

**Angular Service**

```
app.service('MyGraphService', function ($http) {
    this.GetJanu = function () {
        alert('in Service')

        var Sert = $http({
            url: '/Department/GetSalesData',
            method: 'GET',
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            content:{'content-type' :'application/Json'}
        })
        return Sert;
    }
})
```

**Angular Controller**

```
app.controller('GraphCntrls', function ($scope, MyGraphService) {
    $scope.Btnclick = function () {
        alert('in cntr')
        var tt = MyGraphService.GetJanu();
        tt.then(function (d) {
            $scope.DataGraphf = d.data;
        })
    }
})
```

**Cshtml Code**

```
<div>

        <div ng-controller="GraphCntrls">


            <input type="button" ng-click="Btnclick()" value="Click"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm"/>


            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Year</b></th>

                    <th><b>Electronics</b></th>
                    <th><b>Book and Media</b></th>
                    <th><b>Home and KitchenKFC</b></th>

                </tr>
                @*<tr ng-repeat="datf in DataGraphf">*@
                <tr>
                    <td>{{Year}}</td>
                    <td>{{datf.Electronics}}</td>
                    <td>{{datf.BookAndMedia}}</td>
                    <td>{{datf.HomeAndKitchen}}</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: first of all, your json response is an array of arrays.  You might want to convert them to object instead.  add a console.log(d) to the tt.then function call so you can see what is coming back.

Comment: could u please give some code

Comment: @MDGhouse have you added in the page the ng-app directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the table row to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="datf in DataGraphf" ng-if="!$first">
  <td>{{datf[0]}}</td>
  <td>{{datf[1]}}</td>
  <td>{{datf[2]}}</td>
  <td>{{datf[3]}}</td>
</tr>
```

since you are returning an array of arrays, and the first index being table headers. you want to hide the first results element with `ng-if="!$first"`.  Then your subsequent elements are arrays with 4 values, so you have to use array index to access the properties vs obj.Name.

To use obj.Name, you have to return an object instead of an array, e.g.

```
{
  "Year": 1230,
  "Electronics": 123,
  "BookAndMedia" : 1234,
  "HomeAndKitche" : 515
}
```

the response json would be:

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

update: had extra tr tag in original response, shifted ng-if to tr instead

Comment: add this line console.log(d); into tt.then(function (d) {.  what do you see there?

Comment: Thank u soo much Mr.Benny Lin u had given me ans along with explanation

Answer (score 0):

If that's the actual code you're running, it's not going to render the line with 
your ng-repeat in it because you have it commented out server-side.

Edit:

Change it to this:

```
public JsonResult GetSalesData()
{
    using (Ctxdb dc = new Ctxdb())
    {


        var v = (from a in dc.SalesRecords
                 group a by a.SalesDate.Year into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Year = g.Key,
                     Electronics = g.Sum(a => a.Electronics),
                     BookAndMedia = g.Sum(a => a.BookAndMedia),
                     HomeAndKitchen = g.Sum(a => a.HomeAndKitchen)
                 });
        if (v != null)
        {
            var chartData = new object[v.Count()];
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in v)
            {
                j++;
                chartData[j] = new object { Year = i.Year, Electronics = i.Electronics, BookAndMedia = i.BookAndMedia, HomeAndKitchen = i.HomeAndKitchen };
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new {
                Fields = new string[] {"Year", "Electronics", "Books and Media", "Home and KitchenKFC"},
                Data = chartData
            } , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = null, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

and your Angular code to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="datf in DataGraphf.Fields">
    <th>{{datf}}</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="datf in DataGraphf.Data">
    <td>{{datf.Year}}</td>
    <td>{{datf.Electronics}}</td>
    <td>{{datf.BookAndMedia}}</td>
    <td>{{datf.HomeAndKitchen}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: unfortunately i post like that its un comment in my code